# How to get sentence embedding using BERT?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, pytorch, bert

How to get sentence embedding using BERT?

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer
tokenizer=BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
sentence='I really enjoyed this movie a lot.'
#1.Tokenize the sequence:
tokens=tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
print(tokens)
print(type(tokens))
```

## 2. Add [CLS] and [SEP] tokens:

```py
tokens = ['[CLS]'] + tokens + ['[SEP]']
print(" Tokens are \n {} ".format(tokens))
```

## 3. Padding the input:

```py
T=15
padded_tokens=tokens +['[PAD]' for _ in range(T-len(tokens))]
print("Padded tokens are \n {} ".format(padded_tokens))
attn_mask=[ 1 if token != '[PAD]' else 0 for token in padded_tokens  ]
print("Attention Mask are \n {} ".format(attn_mask))
```

## 4. Maintain a list of segment tokens:

```py
seg_ids=[0 for _ in range(len(padded_tokens))]
print("Segment Tokens are \n {}".format(seg_ids))
```

## 5. Obtaining indices of the tokens in BERT’s vocabulary:

```py
sent_ids=tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(padded_tokens)
print("senetence idexes \n {} ".format(sent_ids))
token_ids = torch.tensor(sent_ids).unsqueeze(0) 
attn_mask = torch.tensor(attn_mask).unsqueeze(0) 
seg_ids   = torch.tensor(seg_ids).unsqueeze(0)
```

## Feed them to BERT

```py
hidden_reps, cls_head = bert_model(token_ids, attention_mask = attn_mask,token_type_ids = seg_ids)
print(type(hidden_reps))
print(hidden_reps.shape ) #hidden states of each token in inout sequence 
print(cls_head.shape ) #hidden states of each [cls]

output:
hidden_reps size 
torch.Size([1, 15, 768])

cls_head size
torch.Size([1, 768])
```

Which vector represents the sentence embedding here? Is it `hidden_reps`  or `cls_head` ?

Is there any other way to get sentence embedding from BERT in order to perform similarity check with other sentences?

Comment: There is actually an academic paper for doing so. It is called [S-BERT or Sentence-BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10084). They also have a [github repo](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers) which is easy to work with.

Answer (score 12):

> Which vector represents the sentence embedding here? Is it `hidden_reps` or `cls_head`?

If we look in the [`forward()` method](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L618) of the BERT model, we see the following lines explaining the return types:

```py
outputs = (sequence_output, pooled_output,) + encoder_outputs[1:]  # add hidden_states and attentions if they are here
return outputs  # sequence_output, pooled_output, (hidden_states), (attentions)
```

So the first element of the tuple is the "sentence output" - each token in the input is embedded in this tensor.  In your example, you have 1 input sequence, which was 15 tokens long, and each token was embedding into a 768-dimensional space.

The second element of the tuple is the "pooled output".  You'll notice that the "sequence" dimension has been squashed, so this represents a pooled embedding of the input sequence.

So they both represent the sentence embedding.  You can think of `hidden_reps` as a "verbose" representation, where each token has been embedded.  You can think of `cls_head` as a condensed representation, where the entire sequence has been pooled.

> Is there any other way to get sentence embedding from BERT in order to perform similarity check with other sentences?

Using the `transformers` library is the easiest way I know of to get sentence embeddings from BERT.

There are, however, many ways to measure similarity between embedded sentences.  The simplest approach would be to measure the Euclidean distance between the pooled embeddings (`cls_head`) for each sentence.

Comment: zachdj thanks for the information . So should i use hidden_reps  or cls_head to get sentence vector ?  clas_head has only 1 vector with 768 dimension   but hidden_reps has  15 vectors with 768 dimension   . How should i convert these 15 vectors into single vector ? should i add or do mean or any other way to get the 15 token vectors represented into a single vector .

Comment: There are many ways to pool the 15 token embeddings into a single vector.  You could take use mean pooling or max pooling.  You could also avoid pooling altogether and use all 15 embeddings.

Comment: For your question about whether to use `hidden_reps` or `cls_head`, it just depends on what you're trying to do.  They both represent the sentence.  One represents each token, and one has already been pooled.

Comment: @zachdji thanks for the information .Can you share the syntax for mean pool and max pool
i tired torch.mean(hidden_reps[0],1) but when i tried  to find cosin similarity for 2 different sentences it gave me high score .So not sure whether  im doing the  right way to get the sentence embedding .

Comment: s1=what is your age?
tensor([-0.0106, -0.0101, -0.0144, -0.0115, -0.0115, -0.0116, -0.0173, -0.0071,
        -0.0083, -0.0070], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>)
 
s2='Today is monday' 
tensor([-0.0092, -0.0094, -0.0113, -0.0106, -0.0166, -0.0071, -0.0073, -0.0074,
        -0.0080, -0.0076], grad_fn=<MeanBackward1>)
  
cos = torch.nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=0)  
score was 0.93 .But ideally it should be very less as 2 sentences are not similry not sure why berth is giving high score .

Comment: In that case, cosine similarity may not be a good choice after all.  It was just the first thing that would occur to me.

Comment: Any suggestion on how should i calculate the similarity of sentences then  using BERT?

Comment: You could try euclidean distance.  Intuitively, you would expect similar words to be nearby in the embedding space.  This is certainly true for Word2Vec.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the hidden state corresponding to the first token (`[CLS]`) in `hidden_reps` can be used as a sentence embedding.

By contrast, the pooled output (mistakenly referred to as `hidden states of each [cls]` in your code) proved a bad proxy for a sentence embedding in my experiments.

Answer (score 3):

There is very cool tool called [bert-as-service](https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service) which does the job for you. It maps a sentence to a fixed length word embeddings based on the pre trained model you use. It also allows a lot of parameter tweaking which is covered extensively in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming to this question from Google, I'll share my experience with building sentence embeddings.
With a standard Bert Model you have three options:

- CLS: You take the first vector of the `hidden_state`, which is the token embedding of the classification `[CLS]` token
- Mean pooling: Take the average value across each dimension in the 512 `hidden_state` embeddings, making sure to *exclude* `[PAD]` embeddings
- Max pooling: Take the max value across each dimension in the 512 `hidden_state` embeddings, again *exclude* `[PAD]`

If you're using the standard BERT, mean pooling or CLS are your best bets, both have worked for me in the past.

However, there are BERT models that have been fine-tuned specifically for creating sentence embeddings. They're called *sentence transformers* and one of the easiest ways to use one of these is via the [sentence-transformers](https://www.sbert.net) library.

Generally these models use the *mean pooling* approach, but have been fine-tuned to produce good sentence embeddings, and they far outperform anything a standard Bert Model could do.

If you wanted to fine-tune your own BERT/other transformer, most of the current state-of-the-art models are fine-tuned using [Multiple Negatives Ranking loss](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/fine-tune-sentence-transformers-mnr/) (ps I wrote that article). For this the model learns to distinguish between similar sentence pairs, and after a pretty short training session (just over an hour for me on RTX 3090) you can produce a good quality sentence transformer model.

That being said, there are already many great pretrained models out there, there's a list of some of the [better models here](https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html), although it isn't fully up to date - for example, `flax-sentence-embeddings/all_datasets_v3_mpnet-base` performs better on benchmarks than any of those listed.

Comment: About the [CLS] part, are you taking about take the vector form the last hidden state? or somewhere in the middle of the model?

Comment: @MoslehMahamud from the last hidden state

Comment: If you are taking the CLS output, it is better to take it from the pooler output and not from the first token in the hiddenstates output. The former has some additional processing done (and in my experience) is more accurate. You can print out and see the 2 values differ. Of course avg pooling of all hiddenstates too provides a good representation.

Comment: Some people say don't use pooling. They say train the model with your own data and get embeddings from CLS token. Why do they say that do you think?

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid confusion by anyone reading this page:

pooled_output in the BERT model is NOT a pooling operation applied on the hidden states of all tokens in the sequence.

The pooled_output is generated by applying an additional dense layer on top of  the [CLS] token hidden state.

This pooled_output is the basis on which classification tasks are done in the original BERT paper.

From the TF implementation https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/modeling.py line 227:

```
        first_token_tensor = tf.squeeze(self.sequence_output[:, 0:1, :], axis=1)
        self.pooled_output = tf.layers.dense(
            first_token_tensor,
            config.hidden_size,
            activation=tf.tanh,
            kernel_initializer=create_initializer(config.initializer_range))
```

So to answer the main question:
As other already responded both the [CLS] token and the pooled_output are a fixed-length vector of the whole sentence so you can use both to embed and compare sentences. The difference between them is that the pooled_output is a result of a dense vector applied on top of the [CLS] token representation.

Answer (score 0):

bert-as-service provides a very easy way to generate embeddings for sentences.

It is explained very well in the [bert-as-service repository](https://github.com/hanxiao/bert-as-service):

Installations:

```
pip install bert-serving-server  # server
pip install bert-serving-client  # client, independent of `bert-serving-server`
```

Download one of the pre-trained models available at [here](https://github.com/google-research/bert).

Start the service:

```
bert-serving-start -model_dir /your_model_directory/ -num_worker=4
```

Generate the vectors for the list of sentences:

```
from bert_serving.client import BertClient
bc = BertClient()
vectors=bc.encode(your_list_of_sentences)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent guide on using sentence/text embedding for similarity measure. Important : BERT does not define sentence level - so basically anything between [CLS] and [SEP] is a piece of text for which you can use output embedding.

https://github.com/VincentK1991/BERT_summarization_1/blob/master/notebook/Primer_to_BERT_extractive_summarization_March_25_2020.ipynb

This approach uses [CLS] token value for 768 dimension or basically the cls_head in your question.

As S-BERT is mentioned earlier , it contends taking [CLS] token's embedding does not work very well for text matching , natural language inference etc. They finetune BERT on a loss objective , such that sentences which entail one another has higher similarity score and they use mean pooling of token embedding rather than taking the [CLS]. In the end you will get the same result - a vector of [1,768].

Following link has an excellent tutorial for this -
https://www.pinecone.io/learn/fine-tune-sentence-transformers-mnr/